# How to set a custom field with a default value on wordpress posts?

Tags: php, wordpress, hook, customization

How can i Set a `custom field` with `default value` in wordpress posts?
i used `more types` and `more fields` plugin to create `products` post type and want that all products has a custom field with `force_ssl` name and `true` value!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Advanced Custom Fields plugin offers default values for custom fields:

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/advanced-custom-fields/

Comment: Does it conflict with 'more types' and 'more fields' plugin?

Comment: no it should not conflict with those plugins. and it will even allow you to only show custom fields for specific post types, which you can create obviously with your 'more types' plugin.